# Get from other collection MongoDB Driver PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections: cars and colors and this my data and I want to use join from other collection I know how to do in SQL like this

cars

```
{
    "_id": "5941969741d1024cde2de203",
    "name": "Toyota",
    "price": 26700
}

{
    "_id": "5941a49117ce1f58b7b7c2bf",
    "name": "Cadillac",
    "price": 26700
}
```

Colors

```
{
    "_id": "5941a9db17ce1f58b7b7c2c0",
    "name": "Toyota",
    "color": "Red"
}
```

is there a way to fetch data from these collections as SQL below using PHP mongodb driver

```
SELECT * FROM cars c INNER JOIN colors r ON (c.name = r.name)
```

Comment: [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is the operation listed right up the top of the search results for the very cryptic term ["mongodb join"](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=mongodb+join) Shortly followed by various posts here that would give you examples of usage syntax.

Comment: @NeilLunn I asked after searching but without results. Thanks

Comment: Dude I gave you a link to a google search that shows otherwise. Very easy to find. If you have a specific problem related to usage of the correct thing, then amend your question to show your attempt so you can be pointed in the correct direction. As it stands there is no effort shown here and you are still not describing in a clear way what it is you actually want to do. If you want answers then fix your question to make your case clear. A SQL statement does not clearly identify your intent for a Database that does not talk SQL. Glib comments will simply get you nowhere.

Comment: @NeilLunn could you please see the question now, hope it is clear.

Comment: @NeilLunn could you help me on this?